# Combobox C#, fill with DataTable, but in top the selected ID my database.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

Combobox C#, fill with DataTable, but in top the selected ID my database.

My table is PRODUTO with id PRODUTO.PRO_LOCAL
Table LOCAL: 
1 - Sapatos
2 - Roupas
3 - Acessórios

PRODUTO.PRO_LOCAL = 2, but my combobox fill with top LOCAL = 1, the first from query.

DataTable that fills the combobox:

```
public DataTable RetornaLocal()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = acessoDadosSqlServer.CriarConexao();
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT loc_cod, loc_descricao FROM local ORDER BY loc_descricao";

        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = null;
        sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable.Load(sqlDataReader);
        return dataTable;

    }
```

Combobox in Form FrmProduto :

```
            cbLocal.DisplayMember = "loc_descricao";
            cbLocal.ValueMember = "loc_cod";
            cbLocal.DataSource = localNegocios.RetornaLocal();
```

I want to FrmProduto in change mode show the ID that is table PRODUTO and not the query returned LOCAL norm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it setting the SelectedValue -> produto.pro_local field.
How did :

```
        cbLocal.DisplayMember = "loc_descricao";
        cbLocal.ValueMember = "loc_cod";
        cbLocal.DataSource = localNegocios.RetornaLocal();
        cbLocal.SelectedValue = produto.pro_local ;
```